# This regular expression is for which type of strings

Tags: java, regex

How can I know that any particular regular expression matches which type of input? Like I want to know about `\$\{([\w]+)\}`. Which string will be matched by this regular expression?

```
Pattern placeholder = Pattern.compile("\\$\\{([\\w]+)\\}");
Matcher mat = placeholder.matcher("input");
while (mat.find()) {

}
```

Comment: [What does the regex mean](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean)?

Comment: To know what a regex matches, go to [regex101.com](http://regex101.com) and type in something, modify, experiment, pay attention to the right-hand pane with explanation and read those hints carefully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It accepts E.L access type to variables:

`${somethingHere}`

As comemnted above, you can check that [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean) for more info.

Comment: https://regex101.com/ is a nice website to debug regex

Answer (score 2):

This will find any character within `${}`

The \w metacharacter is used to find a word character.

A word character is a character from a-z, A-Z, 0-9, including the _ (underscore) character.

The other characters are escaped by `\`, `\$` looks for a `$` `\{` looks for `{` and `\}` looks for `}`

The `+` token mean to repeat the character `([\w])` between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible.